# calling Web service in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, web-services

I'm trying to access web service that written in .net. But I identified there is a problem with my javascript code. But I can't identify what it is. Any body plz help me...

This is my JS code

```
 function getID() {
        var id = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
        WebApplication4.myWebService1.getDetails(id, getSMSSucsess); // The problem I think..
      }

function getSMSSucsess(result) {
        document.getElementById("myDev").value = result["status"];
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call server side code from javascript, one lives on the server the other on the client.

The line

```
WebApplication4.myWebService1.getDetails(id, getSMSSucsess);
```

does not exist in javascript.

I would suggest making a [jQuery ajax call](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to the WebService.